# How do I put multiple criteria for a column in a where clause?

Tags: sql

I have five results to retrieve from a table and I want to write a store procedure that will return all desired rows.

I can write the query like that temporarily:

```
Select * from Table where Id = 1 OR Id = 2 or Id = 3
```

I supposed I need to receive a list of `Id`s to split, but how do I write the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: `where id in (...)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if you're just trying to learn SQL, this is a short and good example to get to know the `IN` operator. The following query has the same result as your attempt.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TALBE2)
```

This translates into what is your attempt. And judging by your attempt, this might be the simplest version for you to understand. Although, in the future I would recommend using a `JOIN`.

A `JOIN` has the same functionality as the previous code, but will be a better alternative. If you are curious to read more about `JOINs`, here are a few links from the most important sources

- [Joins - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)
- [and also a visual representation of how different types of JOIN work](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it. The `inner join` will only include rows from T1 that match up with a row from T2 via the `Id` field.

```
select T1.* from T1 inner join T2 on T1.Id = T2.Id
```

In practice, [inner joins are usually preferable to subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577224/424129) for performance reasons.

Comment: Join is by default better than nested select.